# Can Python type hints handle a generic class changing its own type in a method?

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing

I have an existing class that changes an important type upon a certain method call. It looks something like this:

```py
class RememberLast:
    def __init__(self, last):
        self._last = last

    def set(self, new_last):
        self._last = new_last

    def get(self):
        return self._last

remember = RememberLast(5)
type(remember.get())  # int
remember.set('wow')
type(remember.get())  # str
remember.set(4.5)
type(remember.get())  # float
```

Ideally the type of `remember` would change from `RememberLast[int]` to `RememberLast[str]` and then to `RememberLast[float]`. Is there a way to represent this situation with type hints?

Returning `self` with a different type hint in `set()` isn't ideal because there are existing callers. For these existing callers that don't use the return value, the type would stay as `RememberLast[int]` even though the type was "destroyed" and isn't correct anymore.

The existing class I'm referring to is [`twisted.internet.defer.Deferred`](https://github.com/twisted/twisted/blob/dee676b040dd38b847ea6fb112a712cb5e119490/src/twisted/internet/defer.py#L479:L481), which allows chaining callbacks. The type of the last return value becomes the parameter for the next callback. So the type of a `Deferred` can be thought of as the type of the last callback added to it.

Comment: if you know the all possible types then put them in union. like: def get(self) -> Union[int, str, float]:

Comment: Type-hints are for *static* typing. If you change the type at runtime, that's by definition *not* static typing.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a generic class to track the changing type.

Define two generics.

- T = The current type
- R = The type after we call set

```py
from typing import TypeVar, Generic, Type

T = TypeVar("T")
R = TypeVar("R")


class RememberLast(Generic[T]):
    def __init__(self, last: T):
        self._last = last

    def set(self, new_last: R) -> "RememberLast[R]":
        return RememberLast(new_last)

    def get(self) -> T:
        return self._last
```

Note in order for this to work you will need to reassign the results of `set` back to `remember`. We need to do this because the results of `set` hold the new type hinting information.

```py
# int
remember = RememberLast(5)  # RememberLast[int]
print(type(remember.get()))  # <class 'int'>

# str
remember = remember.set("abc")  # RememberLast[str]
print(type(remember.get()))  # <class 'str'>

# float
remember = remember.set(4.5)  # RememberLast[float]
print(type(remember.get()))  # <class 'float'>
```

Comment: but what if RememberLast is subclassed?  and set is rewritten as `type(self)(new_last)` -- you'd like to go from SubClass[T] to SubClass[R] in the typing, not SubClass[T] to RememberLast[R] -- is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume that `RememberLast` must be able to handle things besides `int`s, `string`s, and `float`s (or more than a finite union of types), because otherwise you could just use `Union[int, str, float]`.

I'm unfortunately pessimistic that you can use an annotation more specific than `Any` for two reasons:

1. [mypy's own's documentation](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/dynamic_typing.html) suggests using `Any` for dynamically typed code. If it was possible to use something more specific, they would have said so.
2. [This StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48207561/17769815) asks something similar, and the accepted answer is basically "refactor so you can explicitly define the expected types, or use `Any`".

Answer (score -3):

Unfortunately, type hints in python doesn't prevent the type from changing for example in your snippet if you used the type hints as bellow it will give the same output:

```py
class RememberLast:
    def __init__(self, last: int):
        self._last = last

    def set(self, new_last: int):
        self._last = new_last

    def get(self):
        return self._last

remember = RememberLast(5)
type(remember.get())  # int
remember.set('wow')
type(remember.get())  # str
remember.set(4.5)
type(remember.get())  # float
```

There are two ways to force the methods to take only specific type:

1. Assert with `isinstance`:

```py
class RememberLast:
    def __init__(self, last: int):
        assert isinstance(last, int)
        self._last = last

    def set(self, new_last: int):
        assert isinstance(last, int)
        self._last = new_last

    def get(self):
        assert isinstance(last, int)
        return self._last

remember = RememberLast(5)
type(remember.get())  # int
remember.set('wow')
type(remember.get())  # raises AssertionError
remember.set(4.5)
type(remember.get())  # raises AssertionError
```

2. use [mypy](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) with type hinting before you deploy your code to make sure that types are matching correctly

```
mypy my_python_script.py
```

this should be the output

```
my_python_script.py:26: error: Argument 1 to "set" of "RememberLast" has incompatible type "str"; expected "int"
my_python_script.py:28: error: Argument 1 to "set" of "RememberLast" has incompatible type "float"; expected "int"
Found 2 errors in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

Comment: This doesn't answer OP's question. The code is supposed to take advantage of dynamic typing, and your solution introduces changes which prevent the code from running.