How to dynamically create type annotations in Python?
Normally, one can define a class with some type-annotated fields as follows:
class A:
    a: str

How to do this dynamically using type function?
I know the case when a is assigned to a value, i.e., in the case that
class B:
    a = 'hello world'

we can B = type('B', (), {'a': 'hello world'})
However, I don't know how to add the type annotation information to the type function dynamically.
For the context, we have some functions that read such information to codegen tests and api calls.

It's just an attribute of the class, so you could add '__annotations__': {'a': str} to the dictionary of class attributes.

Maybe this answer will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48207561/how-can-i-add-type-annotations-to-dynamically-created-classes

Do you have class-variables only and should you do some validation of the input afterwards ? If yes, I think that pydantic could be the answer without much pain ?

As @jonrsharpe suggests, we could directly modify the __annotations__ of the class. My understanding is something as follows:
C: type = type('C', (), {})
C.__annotations__['a'] = str

This answers the question.
EDIT
@jonrsharpe suggests that he meant rather (as I understand it) the following:
D: type = type('D', (), {'__annotations__': {'a': str}})

At the moment of this edit, I am not able to be sure whether they are different. For my use cases, both of them do. It feels the second snippet would be better by allowing type function to clean up this extra bit of informations.

This would be a very britle solution in my opinion. What if you assign integer to a ? The annotation will stay unchanged and very misleading ...

@baskettaz The context is we have an existing code base that has these nicely annotated structs to help write certain code (X). The annotations were helpful for both codegen and static analysis. But it turns out in our use cases, X can always be programmatically generated. So the static analysis part would not be needed.  I do agree that the generated classes will not be helpful for type checking, but second to massively rewrite the whole layer of functionality, I think this is reasonable.

My point was that you could include annotations in the dynamic type(...) call by adding the relevant "dunder" attribute to the class dictionary. If you're writing a regular class, use the regular annotations.
